# Pandas/Numpy help vectorizing or using df.apply

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

So lets say I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
    x1    x2    x3    y1    y2    y3    z1    z2    z3
1   10    10.1  9.9   1     2     3     4     5     6
2   11    11.1  10.9  2     3     4     5     6     7
...
```

I want to make a 3 columns called `[xave,yave,zave]` and then have each element in it be the average of the three columns in the df above (this is just an example, I need to do this operation 6 times on 6 sets of three columns)

```
    x1    x2    x3    y1    y2    y3    z1    z2    z3    xave    yave    zave
1   10    10.1  9.9   1     2     3     4     5     6     10      2       5
2   11    11.1  10.9  2     3     4     5     6     7     11      3       6
...
```

Right now I am doing this by looping through the dataframes index and using `df.set_value(index,col,val)` to do this at each index value.

`for index in df.index:
     df.set_value(index = index, col = x1, value = np.average(df.iloc[index,[0:2])`

I feel like there has to be a way to do this with a `df.apply()` or maybe a lambda function.  I just need to increase the speed of the function otherwise it takes too long to analyze a large amount of files.  I have another script that loops through a directory and grabs all .csv files inside it. It then performs the analysis I am doing and saves the filename and values as an array.  The directory is ~3000 files the amount of data can vary from 200kb to 4000kb in each.

I am not sure of the exact timing I am looking up how to figure that out now.

Comment: Also respectfully - you might want to take an hour or two to read over the first few sections of the Pandas docs, it could help considerably with your Pandas workflow.

Comment: The built-in way to time code is to [use the timeit module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module#). An easier way is to use [IPython's `%timeit` command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29280470/190597).

Comment: I'm sorry I am sure this is a basic question and I am working on improving my understanding of python and pandas but I don't use it every day so sometimes the indexing of dataframes confuses me.  I edited my question to make it clearer and why it is different than the question yall flagged.