# Manipulating an entity before saving to DB

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an issue understanding something here. I'm trying to manipulate a field from an entity that is being created, but it is not working as expected.

In short I'm trying to change a field that has emails by splitting them and then adding a `;` separator to distinguish the different emails before saving to the database.

This is my code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(Models.Requests.Request newRequest)
{
    newRequest.RequestStatusID = (int)RequestStatusEnum.Requested;
    newRequest.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
    newRequest.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    newRequest.LastRequestDate = DateTime.Now;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(newRequest.CCRecipients))
    {
        string[] emailSeparators;
        string ccRecipients = "";
        emailSeparators = newRequest.CCRecipients.Split(new Char[] { ' ', ',', ';' });

        foreach (var email in emailSeparators)
        {
            //ccRecipients.Concat(email + "; ");
            
            // I have tried two different ways to concatenate the string
            ccRecipients = email.Trim() + "; ";
        }

        // This is where I'm trying to manipulate the string into the field
        // To my understanding this is possible but I could be wrong
        newRequest.CCRecipients = ccRecipients;
    }

    await _changeControlContext.AddAsync(newRequest);
    await _changeControlContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Other code that is being done

    return new RedirectToPageResult("RedirectsToAnotherPage");
}
```

There's probably a better way to handle this but for now I want to understand why this is not working or what am I over looking.

In theory it should work but it is not. What could be the issue here?

**EDIT**: when I mean not working i mean that the values of `CCRecipients` field of said request are not being save in the database.

For example: `RandomEmail@test.com; RandomEmail2@test.com`. But in the database, nothing appears is stored. It's a white space instead of null. Sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: "Not working" is not a good description of problem.  Not working how???  Error out?  Not changing?  Changing to some random value???

Comment: Ah yes sorry for the lack of clarity. I have edited the post. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Have you put breakpoint inside your `foreach` to check the value of email variable?

Comment: How it is currently set it is a complete nightmare. No local development to test any change I have to deploy the project. This is a project from work. Don't know why this is setup the way it is but I'm fighting for my life (Like Ray J would say) to change this. In short it is not possible to add a breakpoint

Comment: I am not sure how I can help if you can't even help yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the existing line of code

`ccRecipients = email.Trim() + "; ";`

with

`ccRecipients = ccRecipients + email.Trim() + "; ";`

OR with a [better approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307518/which-operator-vs-should-be-used-for-performance-in-place-vs-not-in-pla) (as mentioned by @Masoud Andalibi)

`ccRecipients += email.Trim() + "; ";`

Comment: lol just noticed his mistake. although `ccRecipients += email.Trim() + "; ";`  is a better approach.

Comment: OMG. I can't believe I forgot the + sign. That was the missing piece thank you very much. I knew something ws up but couldn't see it lol