# How to Filter a DataFrame Where a Column Contains Values Stored in a List?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
"""DataFrame of tweets"""
tweet_df = pd.DataFrame(text_tweets, columns = ["Date", "Tweet"])


"""Terms to search tweets"""
TweetsCheckList = ["Word", "Word2",..., "Word100"]

"""Empty Filtered DataFrame based on TweetsCheckList"""
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Date", "Tweet"])

for y in tweet_df.iterrows():
    for x in TweetsCheckList:
        if x in tweet_df.Tweet:
            df2.append(y)
```

Hey everyone, just had a question.

I wanted to ask if anyone could help me essentially filter out a dataframe based on entries in a list. I have certain words I want to check if they're in any tweets stored in a DataFrame. I'm unsure why this isn't working, so if anyone had any guidance it'd be very helpful, thank you!

My understanding is that I'm going to be searching each row of the dataframe

Every time I search a row, I take every item in the TweetsCheckList, and check if it's in the current tweet. And if so, I append that tweet to the empty DataFrame. Why is this not proper?

Update:

I have tried the following:

```
for y in tweet_df:
    for x in covid19TweetsCheckList:
        if tweet_df.Tweet.str.contains(x):
            covid_df.append(y)
```

To no avail...it's telling me:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

If anyone can point me towards the solution to this error, I'd be very appreciative!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter numpy array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51618953/filter-numpy-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the DataFrame using boolean conditions to check if any of the words are present in the column, something like this:

```
# Setup:
tweet_df = pd.DataFrame({"Tweet": ["Word ...", "something else", "blah Word2"]})
TweetsCheckList = ["Word", "Word2", "Word100"]

# Solution:
conditions = False
for w in TweetsCheckList:
    conditions = conditions | (tweet_df["Tweet"].str.contains(w))
tweet_df.loc[conditions]
```