# Python script execution time

Tags: python

How do I measure the execution time of a python script without adding the code everytime like import timeit (start time - end time) in the script.
I mean what can be done only once to show the execution time whenever i run a script.

Comment: You can use ipython's %timeit magic to time single statements. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280470/what-is-timeit-in-python. If you want the execution time for the entire script, you can just use the `time` command on the terminal https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52313/how-to-get-execution-time-of-a-script-effectively

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes, it's not possible to show the time of a python script without adding the code(start time- end time). But you can show the execution time of a python script like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
startTime = datetime.now()
#You can do anyting here
print("Hello World")
print(datetime.now() - startTime)
```

If you are on Linux, you can try:

```
time ./script.py
```

This works under OSX. This also works under `cygwin` on Windows. Though I haven't personally tested it because I am on a Linux machine.

Hope it helps :)