# How can I create xticks with varying intervals?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, xticks

I am drawing a line chart using matplotlib as shown below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import io

temp = u"""
tenor,yield
1M,5.381
3M,5.451
6M,5.505
1Y,5.393
5Y,4.255
10Y,4.109
"""

data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=",")
plt.plot(data['tenor'], data['yield'])
```

Output: The tick intervals on the x-axis are all the same.

[image]

What I want : Set the tick interval of the x-axis differently as shown in the screen below

Is there any way to set tick intvel differently?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the column `'tenor'`, `'M'` represents month and `'Y'` represents year. Create a `'Month'` column with `'Y'` scaled by 12 Months.

It's more concise to plot the `data` directly with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), and use [`.set_xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html) to change the xtick-labels.

**Tested in `python 3.12.0`, `pandas 2.1.1`, `matplotlib 3.8.0`**

```py
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=",")

# Add a column "Month" from the the column "tenor"
data["Month"] = data['tenor'].apply(lambda x : int(x[:-1]) *12 if 'Y' in x else int(x[:-1]))

# plot yield vs Month
ax = data.plot(x='Month', y='yield', figsize=(17, 5), legend=False)

# set the xticklabels
_ = ax.set_xticks(data.Month, data.tenor)
```

The output:

[image: Output]

---

### `.apply` with a `lambda` function is fastest

- Given 6M rows

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({'tenor': ['1M', '3M', '6M', '1Y', '5Y', '10Y'] * 1000000})
```

#### Compare Implementations with [`%timeit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29280612/7758804) in JupyterLab

- `.apply` & `lambda`

```py
%timeit data['tenor'].apply(lambda x: int(x[:-1]) *12 if 'Y' in x else int(x[:-1]))

2 s ± 50.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

- `.apply` with a function call

```py
def scale(x):
    v = int(x[:-1])
    return v * 12 if 'Y' in x else v

%timeit data['tenor'].apply(scale)

2.02 s ± 20.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

- Vectorized `np.where` with `assignment expression`

```py
%timeit np.where(data.tenor.str.contains('Y'), (v := data.tenor.str[:-1].astype(int)) * 12 , v)

2.44 s ± 26.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

- Vectorized `np.where` without `assignment expression`

```py
%timeit np.where(data.tenor.str.contains('Y'), data.tenor.str[:-1].astype(int) * 12 , data.tenor.str[:-1].astype(int))

3.36 s ± 5.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Correct. M means Month and Y means Year. Thank you for your tips. Though I have to handle overlay X-axis problem , it would be very helpful tips for me.

Comment: @user3685918 Note the update with more concise code.

Comment: @ Trenton McKinney Thank you very much for your update and benchmark to the answer !

Comment: You’re welcome!